# Why don't Haskell compilers facilitate deterministic memory management?

Tags: memory-management, haskell, garbage-collection

With the wealth of type information available why can't Haskell runtimes avoid running GC to clean up? It should be possible to figure out all usages and insert appropriate calls to alloc/release in the compiled code, right? This would avoid the overhead of a runtime GC.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is sensible to ask whether functional programming languages can do less GC by tracking usage. Although the general problem of whether some data can safely be discarded is undecidable (because of conditional branching), it's surely plausible to work harder statically and find more opportunities for direct deallocation.

It's worth paying attention to the work of Martin Hofmann and the team on the Mobile Resource Guarantees project, who made type-directed memory (de/re)allocation a major theme. The thing that makes their stuff work, though, is something Haskell doesn't have in its type system --- linearity. If you know that a function's input data are *secret* from the rest of the computation, you can reallocate the memory they occupy. The MRG stuff is particularly nice because it manages a realistic exchange rate between deallocation for one type and allocation for another which turns into good old-fashioned pointer-mangling underneath a purely functional exterior. In fact, lots of lovely parsimonious mutation algorithms (e.g. pointer-reversing traversal, overwrite-the-tail-pointer construction, etc) can be made to look purely functional (and checked for nasty bugs) using these techniques.

In effect, the linear typing of resources gives a conservative but mechanically checkable approximation to the kind of usage analysis that might well help to reduce GC. Interesting questions then include how to mix this treatment cleanly (deliberate adverb choice) with the usual persistent deal. It seems to me that quite a lot of intermediate data structures has an initial single-threaded phase in recursive computation, before being either shared or dropped when the computation finishes. It may be possible to reduce the garbage generated by such processes.

TL;DR There are good typed approaches to usage analysis which cut GC, but Haskell has the wrong sort of type information just now to be particularly useful for this purpose.

Comment: Linearity doesn't play well with laziness

Comment: You assert this with a degree of certainty, but you don't provide me with a basis to acheive that certainty for myself. You may be right, but would you care to expand on the problems which lead you to this wisdom? I know Clean's uniqueness types are not exactly a linear type system, but Clean is lazy. Meanwhile, some heretics have suggested that Haskell should be more clearly delimited in its laziness, which might make room for other kinds of discipline. I imagine there is still scope for doubt here, and with it, innovation.

Comment: Hm, I'm guessing the word "discipline" here was chosen roughly as deliberately as "cleanly" was. Personally, I'd sooner distinguish recursive from corecursive code than strict from lazy, but that's neither here nor there. Of more immediate relevance to Haskell, I wonder if some form of scoped allocation could be done using higher-rank types *a la* `runST`. That's about the opposite of inferring such properties by code analysis, though!

Comment: A good strict-vs-lazy separation would probably need a good recursion-vs-corecursion separation. A `runST` trick might let us stack allocation regions, but it's not obvious that stacking is the only structure we need. In this brave new world of diffuse interconnected processors, we could indeed use types to say where (and when!) stuff is as well as what it is. We might well imagine having a fixed lifetime data region where everything allocated and not explicitly exported elsewhere gets crunched at the end. Interesting times ahead!

Comment: What!? Can I have a link to this MRG paper?

Answer (score 14):

Region-based memory management is what programmers in C and C++ often end up programming by hand: Allocate a chunk of memory ("region", "arena", etc.), allocate the individual data in it, use them and eventually deallocate the whole chunk when you know none of the individual data are needed any more.  Work in the 90s by Tofte, Aiken, and others (incl. yours truly, with our respective colleagues), has shown that it is possible to statically infer region allocation and deallocation points automatically ("region inference") in such a way as to guarantee that chunks are never freed too early and, in practice, early enough to avoid having too much memory being held for long after the last data in it was needed.  The ML Kit for Regions, for example, is a full Standard ML compiler based on region inference.  In its final version it is combined with intra-region garbage collection: If the static inference shows there is a long-living region, use garbage collection inside it.  You get to have your cake and eat it, too: You have garbage collection for long living data, but a lot of data is managed like a stack, even though it would end in a heap ordinarily.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
func a = if some_computation a
    then a
    else 0
```

To know whether `a` is garbage after calling `func a`, the compiler has to be able to know the result of `some_computation a`. If it could do that in the general case (which requires solving the halting problem), thrn there'd be no need to emit code for this function at all, let alone garbage collect it. Type information is not sufficient.

Comment: This might be kind of dumb, but don't we just know `a` is garbage in the else branch, and we just insert the call to collect on that branch?

Comment: @hLk What if there are other references to `a` around? It was passed in from somewhere that had a reference to it, fof example. I didn't write this super well 9 years ago, but the point is after running `y = func x`, `y` may or may not be a reference to the value x. You need to identify all of the things to that *actually* refer to x to know where to statically compile a call to collect x, not just all of the things that *might* be references to x.

Answer (score 5):

It's not easy to determine object lifetime with lazy evaluation.  The JHC compiler does have (had?) region memory management which tries to release memory by deallocation when the lifetime is over.

I'm also curious exactly what you mean by deterministic memory management.

Comment: I'm guessing that by "deterministic" he means "agressive" memory management, in other words, "get rid of it at the very moment it becomes unnecessary", rather than "get rid of it whenever the GC detects it is unnecessary".

Comment: Getting rid of something the moment it becomes unnecessary is undecidable.  Maybe he means something like reference counting which is an approximation to that.  But it is still not exactly deterministic.

Comment: Reference counting is "referentially transparent", in a sense of speaking, isn't it? Meaning, if the program is given the same inputs, it should perform deallocations at the same times. So it's sort of mostly kinda deterministic.

Comment: @Dan Other methods of GC are equally deterministic.  Given the same inputs the deallocations will happen at the same time.  This is not true in ghc, because the rts uses threads and timers, but it doesn't have to do that.

Comment: @Dan,@augustss... "Meaning, if the program is given the same inputs, it should perform deallocations at the same times".. yes thats what I meant as deterministic. Understood why it is not true in ghc due to rts employing threads .

Answer (score -1):

Type information has mostly to do with compile time where as memory management is a runtime thing, so I don't think they are related to each other.